# How to replace native comment_count with Comments Evolved aggregate count

Tags: php, wordpress, function, plugins, filter

### What I Am Trying To DO

I am using a plugin called Comments Evolved which aggregates comments that are tabbed from Faceook, G+, and WordPress native.

I am trying to replace the native `comments_number` number with the number from the plugin's aggregate count.

### The Problem

I want to do this via functions.php but I am having trouble as it seems to only be pulling the Facebook comments count.   I suspect my filter has not worked and hence it's only pulling what WordPress native would pull.

### What I've Tried

Currently I am using this filter:

```
// Replace native comment count with Comments Evolved comment in native comments_number function
function comments_evolved_number() {
    $number = comments_evolved_get_total_count();
}
apply_filters('comments_number', 'comments_evolved_number');
```

but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick as it only shows the number of comments in the Facebook tab.

In my index.php, I am using this to pull the comments:

```
        <?php comments_number( 'Say somethin\'!', '1 comment', '% comments' ) ?>
```

I've also tried `add_filter` but that seems to do nothing as the comments aren't output at all.  I've searched everywhere, forums, WordPress codex, plugin GitHub, and even looked through similar threads dealing with Disqus comments, but I can't find the reason my filter is failing.

What am I doing wrong?

### UPDATE 1

This seems to work:

```
function wpse_comments_evolved_number( $count ) 
{
    // Override the comment count
    if( function_exists( 'comments_evolved_get_total_count' ) )
        $count = comments_evolved_get_total_count();

    // We must then return the value:
    return $count;
}
add_filter( 'get_comments_number', 'wpse_comments_evolved_number');
```

...but on testing, it seems that it does Not pull the Facebook comment count, though it pulls and aggregates all the rest:

Comments Evolved constructs `comments_evolved_get_total_count()` like this:

```
function comments_evolved_get_total_count() {
  $total_count = 0;

  $wordpress_count = comments_evolved_get_wordpress_count();
  //$wordpress_count = get_comments_number();

  $gplus_count = comments_evolved_get_gplus_count();
  $trackback_count = comments_evolved_get_trackback_count();
  $facebook_count = comments_evolved_get_facebook_count();
  $disqus_count = comments_evolved_get_disqus_count();

  $total_count = $total_count + $wordpress_count + $gplus_count + $trackback_count + $facebook_count + $disqus_count;
  return $total_count;
}
//add_filter('get_comments_number', 'comments_evolved_get_total_count', 4269);
```

The Facebook `comments_evolved_get_facebook_count()` is constructed like this:

```
function comments_evolved_get_facebook_count($url = "") {
  if(empty($url)){ $url = get_permalink(); }
  $link = 'https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . urlencode($url);
  $link_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get($link));
  $json = json_decode($link_body);
  return $json->$url->comments;
}
```

I don't see any errors in that and in other places it pulls the correct Facebook count (I think -- not sure).

#### What did work but doesn't seem efficient/satisfactory

```
function comment_count_agg() {
  $total_count = 0;

  //$wordpress_count = comments_evolved_get_wordpress_count();
  $wordpress_count = get_comments_number();

  $gplus_count = comments_evolved_get_gplus_count();
  $trackback_count = comments_evolved_get_trackback_count();
  $facebook_count = comments_evolved_get_facebook_count();
  $disqus_count = comments_evolved_get_disqus_count();

  $total_count = $total_count + $wordpress_count + $gplus_count + $trackback_count + $facebook_count + $disqus_count;
  return $total_count;
}
add_filter('comments_evolved_get_total_count', 'comment_count_agg', 4270);
add_filter('get_comments_number', 'comments_evolved_get_total_count', 4271);
```

...though I am not *exactly* sure why.

I tried it this way because (a) I figured something in the plugin is messing with the aggregate count before the filter is applied and (b) because I thought maybe the priorities were somehow an issue.

### UPDATE 2

I've actually tried both above methods on 2 different sites.  On 1 site, everything works perfectly with either method.

On site 2, it fails to pull in the Facebook count towards the whole aggregate count.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
function wpse_comments_evolved_number( $count ) 
{
    // Override the comment count
    if( function_exists( 'comments_evolved_get_total_count' ) )
        $count = comments_evolved_get_total_count();

    // We must then return the value:
    return $count;
}
add_filter( 'get_comments_number', 'wpse_comments_evolved_number');
```

However, on one site that I've tried it, the Facebook count is not being pulled in.  On another, everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, your discussion helps me to hide the total number of comments header by using `get_comments_number` hook from the frontend as well as I hide all comments by `comments_array` hook.

```
// Hide comments counter
add_filter( 'get_comments_number', 0);
// Hide existing comments
add_filter('comments_array', '__return_empty_array', 10, 2);
// Remove the comment form
add_filter( 'comments_open', '__return_false' );
```